# Create a ListObject Table from a collection of arrays Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, collections, listobject

So, I have a collection of arrays (that I originally had in a 2d array but due to the variable nature of the size of the data I decided a collection may be better), the arrays of which are a fixed length.

I want to basically dump this whole collection into a listObject table. This works fine when using a 2D array with table.resize(x,y).value = array but does not want to play ball when replacing the array with collection; I get a "Runtime Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

This is what did work (very stripped back code):

```
'mailData = array of arrays of email data (sender,date,subject,etc)
Set LO = xlWs.ListObjects("Emails")
Set LR = LO.ListRows.Add.Range
LR.Resize(UBound(mailData), UBound(mailData,2)).value = mailData
```

And this is what id like to work but doesn't:

```
'mailData = Collection of arrays of email data (sender,date,subject,etc)
Set LO = xlWs.ListObjects("Emails")
Set LR = LO.ListRows.Add.Range
LR.Resize(mailData.count, UBound(mailData(1))).value = mailData
```

I really want to avoid looping and writing to excel for each row as there are a lot of rows and it would be a massive performance hit.

Thanks.

Edit:
I ended up just writing a "convert collection to array" function; was the only simple way that seemed to just work.

```
Function colToAr(col As collection) As Variant
     Dim outAr(1 To col.Count, 7) As Variant
     Dim i, j As Integer
     For i = 1 To col.Count
         For j = 0 To 6
             outAr(i, j) = col(i)(j)
         Next
     Next
     colToAr = outAr
End Function
```

Comment: You have to loop, but you can write each array in one go. You don't actually have to write row by row, unless each array corresponds to one row.

Comment: yeah each collection entry (array) is a row, each value in the array is each cell in the row. if i really have to loop that sucks, can you dump dictionaries straight into a table?

Comment: More importantly, why is each array one row? Seems like a design flaw. "I decided a collection may be better" - maybe not. Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Well, like I said I was originally using a 2d array for the lot, this worked fine but then i couldn't easily shrink it when i need to remove certain elements. 
So this is basically a list of emails and each email has a set of fields, to me this is the only way to cleanly organise as it is essentially an array of arrays?

Comment: would recordset be a better option instead of collection or array?